# Check the presence of file which starts with specific string in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, conditionals

I have a directory that contains multiple files. I can easily determine the presence or absence of a file with the following command.

```
\IfFileExists{sample.png}{....}{}
```

But how can I check the presence of a file which starts with a specific string. For example suppose there are the following files in my folder:

```
mapScan.png
mapTest.png
sample.tex
```

I am going to have an If condition that checks the presence of file which start with **map**.

*Point:* I should use **pdflatex** as LaTeX compiler.

Comment: You can't, because TeX needs a full file name to find a file (unless you use `-shell-escape` and something like `map*`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to enable shell-escape.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfGenericFileExistsTF}{mmm}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich~#1 } { \cctab_select:N \c_code_cctab } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_tmpa_tl { #3 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\IfGenericFileExistsTF{map*.png}{\typeout{YES}}{\typeout{NO}}

\IfGenericFileExistsTF{Map*.png}{\typeout{YES}}{\typeout{NO}}

\stop
```

In my test setting there are two files `mapScan.png` and `mapTest.png`, but no file starting with `Map`. The console would print

```
YES
NO
```

for the two shown commands. The setting of `\c_code_cctab` is used to ignore spaces (and endlines).

You can use whatever set of commands you want in the second and third arguments to `\IfGenericFileExistsTF`.

Alternative implementation with `l3sys-shell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3sys-shell}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfGenericFileExistsTF}{mmm}
 {
  \sys_shell_split_ls:nN { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
  \tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 } } { #3 } { #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\IfGenericFileExistsTF{map*.png}{\typeout{YES}}{\typeout{NO}}

\IfGenericFileExistsTF{Map*.png}{\typeout{YES}}{\typeout{NO}}

\stop
```

Explanation: if there is no match, the sequence will contain a single empty item.

Comment: You could use `l3sys-shell` to get the directory listing in a system-agnostic fashion

Comment: @JosephWright Not sure what you mean, but I replaced `ls` with `kpsewhich`, which is in fact OS independent.

Comment: I was thinking of `\sys_shell_split_ls:nN`, but using `kpsewhich` as you say also works :)

Comment: @JosephWright Added. But perhaps the sequence should be empty if the listing returns nothing, rather than having an empty item. Not a big deal anyway.

Comment: I'll look at that